# empty targetValue in rich listShuttle

Tags: jsf, richfaces, javabeans

I'm trying to select actions from a list of given ones. It's a `List<String>`, so I don't use a converter. I don't know, why there is no assignment is taking place. Whatever I shift from one side to the other is only visible in the web, but the `targetValue` stays empty. Why? Do you see anything?

Here is a part of the `.xhtml` file (wich is `ui:included` in an other `xhtml` file, where a `h:form` element is wrapped around):

```
        <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold" value="#{labels['maint.works']}" />
        <r:listShuttle sourceValue="#{orderEdit.unselectedActionList}" var="_act"
            targetValue="#{orderEdit.selectedActionList}" style="margin:0px 0px 0px -5px; font-weight:normal"
            sourceCaptionLabel="#{labels['maint.works.list']}" targetCaptionLabel="#{labels['maint.works.choice']}"
            showButtonLabels="false" orderControlsVisible="false" fastOrderControlsVisible="false"
            listsHeight="150" sourceListWidth="170" targetListWidth="170" >
            <r:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{_act}" />
            </r:column>
        </r:listShuttle>
```

Here is my `Bean`:

```
    // list of "Ausgeführte Arbeiten"
    List<TblUserAction> actionListDb = dataStore.getActionByMatchCode(userInfo.getUserName());
    for(TblUserAction action : actionListDb) {
        unselectedActionList.add(action.getAction());
    }
```

and the `getters` and `setters` in that `Bean`:

```
public List<String> getSelectedActionList() {
    return selectedActionList;
}

public void setSelectedActionList(List<String> selectedActionList) {
    this.selectedActionList = selectedActionList;

public List<String> getUnselectedActionList() {
    return unselectedActionList;
}

public void setUnselectedActionList(List<String> unselectedActionList) {
    this.unselectedActionList = unselectedActionList;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you aren't sending any data to the server, so the server doesn't know there have been any changes.

You can use a submit button:

```
<a4j:commanButton process="listShuttleId" value="Submit">
```

or you can have the changes sent to server as they're happening by putting this inside the listShuttle:

```
<a4j:support event="onlistchanged" />
```